# Applying the same operations on multiple .csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis, read.csv

I have six .csv files. They overall size is approximately 4gigs. I need to clean each and do some data analysis task on each. These operations are the same for all the frames.
This is my code for reading them.

```
#df = pd.read_csv(r"yellow_tripdata_2018-01.csv")
#df = pd.read_csv(r"yellow_tripdata_2018-02.csv")
#df = pd.read_csv(r"yellow_tripdata_2018-03.csv")
#df = pd.read_csv(r"yellow_tripdata_2018-04.csv")
#df = pd.read_csv(r"yellow_tripdata_2018-05.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(r"yellow_tripdata_2018-06.csv")
```

Each time I run the kernel, I activate one of the files to be read. 
I am looking for a more elegant way to do this. I thought about doing a for-loop. Making a list of file names and then reading them one after the other but I don't want to merge them together so I think another approach must exist. I have been searching for it but it seems all the questions lead to concatenating the files read at the end.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 3):

### **Use `for` and `format` like this. I use this every single day:**

```
number_of_files = 6

for i in range(1, number_of_files+1):
    df = pd.read_csv("yellow_tripdata_2018-0{}.csv".format(i)))

    #your code here, do analysis and then the loop will return and read the next dataframe
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it going to work in jupyter notebook? I have a number of cells that come after this one

Comment: Yes it's working fine. You should use this when you want to start reading the .csv files.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list to hold all of the dataframes:

```
number_of_files = 6
dfs = []

for file_num in range(len(number_of_files)):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(f"yellow_tripdata_2018-0{file_num}.csv")) #I use Python 3.6, so I'm used to f-strings now. If you're using Python <3.6 use .format()
```

Then to get a certain dataframe use:

```
df1 = dfs[0]
```

**Edit:**

As you are trying to keep from loading all of these in memory, I'd resort to streaming them. Try changing the for loop to something like this:

```
for file_num in range(len(number_of_files)):
    with open(f"yellow_tripdata_2018-0{file_num}.csv", 'wb') as f:
        dfs.append(csv.reader(iter(f.readline, '')))
```

Then just use a for loop over `dfs[n]` or `next(dfs[n])` to read each line into memory.

**P.S.**

You may need multi-threading to iterate through each one at the *same* time.

**Loading/Editing/Saving:** - *using `csv` module*

Ok, so I've done a lot of research, python's `csv` module does load one line at a time, it's most likely in the mode we are opening it in. *(explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28277372/225020))*

If you don't want to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) *(which chunking may honestly be the answer, just implement that into @seralouk's answer if so)*, otherwise, then yes! This *below* is in my mind would be the best approach, we just need to change a couple of things.

```
number_of_files = 6
filename = "yellow_tripdata_2018-{}.csv"

for file_num in range(number_of_files):
    #notice I'm opening the original file as f in mode 'r' for read only
    #and the new file as nf in mode 'a' for append
    with open(filename.format(str(file_num).zfill(2)), 'r') as f,
         open(filename.format((str(file_num)+"-new").zfill(2)), 'a') as nf:
        #initialize the writer before looping every line
        w = csv.writer(nf)
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            #do your "data cleaning" (THIS IS PER-LINE REMEMBER)
        #save to file
        w.writerow(row)
```

**Note:**

You may want to consider using a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)  and/or [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter), I'd prefer them over regular reader/writers as I find them easier to understand.

**Pandas Approach** - *using chunks*

[PLEASE READ this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29908754/225020) - if you'd like to steer away from my csv approach and stick with Pandas :) It literally seems like it's the same issue as yours and the answer is what you're asking for.

Basically Panda's allows for you to partially load a file as chunks, execute any alterations, then you can write those chunks to a new file. Below is majorly from that answer but I did do some more reading up myself in the docs

```
number_of_files = 6
chunksize = 500 #find the chunksize that works best for you
filename = "yellow_tripdata_2018-{}.csv"

for file_num in range(number_of_files):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename.format(str(file_num).zfill(2))chunksize=ch)
        # Do your data cleaning
        chunk.to_csv(filename.format((str(file_num)+"-new").zfill(2)), mode='a') #see again we're doing it in append mode so it creates the file in chunks
```

For more info on chunking the data see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) as well it's good reading for those such as yourself getting headaches over these memory issues.

Comment: but I don't want to keep them all in the memory at the same time. The accumulate to almost 4 gigs.

Comment: I'd refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556862/225020) answer. What you're looking for then is streaming the loading of the csv file. Although to do all files at the same time you'll need to use multi-threading

Comment: Edited my answer. Hopefully my code makes sense, please advise if not. GL

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use this strategy but is it possible to go with the for loop and formatting. Like the other answers have suggested? I just get confused about how working in a notebook is when I create a for-loop. in the first iteration, I read the first data-frame. Now, all the other cells are considered as operations inside the loop?

Comment: For loop and formatting? What do you mean formatting?

Comment: @parastoo91 see my answer below. No need to load anything in memory

Comment: He said the files are 4 GB each. I assume this will not fit into memory for him as it's too large. Streaming should only load one line at a time into memory if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: what I want to do is this: read the data-frame, do the data cleaning, put the resulted data frame in a new .csv file. Do these operations on the rest of the files I have. I don't want to get memory error so I need to read these dataframes one by one.

Comment: @parastoo91 I edited. I did a crap load of research on it as I had minimal experience as deep as I thought needed originally. I believe that last edit should help you! If not, feel free to let me know!

Comment: Ok, last edit I hope, I included all the pandas stuff I found. Chunksize is what is need for that! Have a look

Answer (score 2):

Use `glob.glob` to get all files with similar names:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("yellow_tripdata_2018-0?.csv")
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    # manipulate df
    df.to_csv(f)
```

This will match `yellow_tripdata_2018-0<any one character>.csv`. You can also use `yellow_tripdata_2018-0*.csv` to match `yellow_tripdata_2018-0<anything>.csv` or even `yellow_tripdata_*.csv` to match all csv files that start with `yellow_tripdata`.

Note that this also only loads one file at a time.

Comment: what files contains? is it a list of the names of my files?

Comment: yes, files contains the list of the files that match the pattern (you could try that by ``print(files)``). In the pattern ``?`` matches any **one** character (including ``?`` itself) and ``*`` matches as many characters as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use os.listdir() to make a list of files you can loop through?

```
samplefiles = os.listdir(filepath)
for filename in samplefiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

where filepath is the directory containing multiple csv's?

Or a loop that changes the filename:

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    df = pd.read_csv(r"yellow_tripdata_2018-0%s.csv") % ( str(i))
```

Comment: Thank you. How does this works? I have now the first data frame in memory. Then I run all the other cells. After all the cells executed, notebooks automatically reads the second dataframe in the files folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
# import libraries 
import pandas as pd
import glob

# store file paths in a variable

project_folder = r"C:\file_path\"

# Save all file path in a variable
 
all_files_paths = glob.glob(project_folder + "/*.csv")

# Create a list to save whole data
li = []

# Use list comprehension to iterate over all files; and append data in each file to list

list_all_data = [li.append(pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)) for filename in all_files]

# Convert list to pandas dataframe
df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```